# JSPM bundle fails when use node-sass module

Tags: jspm, node-sass

I'm triyng to build a module for Jspm using node-sass
but when i try to bundle the package I'll receive this error:

jspm bundle-sfx index

> Building the single-file sfx bundle for index...
>
> err  Error: Error loading "npm:node-sass@3.1.2/package.json!github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0" at file:/Users/davide/Learning/JspmNodeSass/jspm_packages/npm/node-sass@3.1.2/package.json
>        Error loading "npm:node-sass@3.1.2/package.json!github:systemjs/plugin-json@0.1.0" from "index" at file:/Users/davide/Learning/JspmNodeSass/index.js
>        ENOENT, open '/Users/davide/Learning/JspmNodeSass/jspm_packages/npm/node-sass@3.1.2/package.json'

This is the sequence to create from scratch the project and create the error:

```
mkdir JspmNodeSass
cd JspmNodeSass/
npm init
npm install --save-dev jspm
jspm init
jspm install -save npm:node-sass
```

create an index.js with the folowing content:

```
// index.js
var sass = require('node-sass');
```

..then run

```
jspm bundle-sfx index
```

Comment: Maybe could be some problem with non-pure javascript?

Comment: Trying to do SASS with JSPM (same here)? Did you ever figure it out?